# ngFileUpload is not injecting correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cloudinary, ng-file-upload

Well "hello all", my problem is I need to inject 'ngFileUpload' on my escuelasDeportivas.app.js. My code for doing this is:

```
var escuelasDeportivas = angular.module('escuelasDeportivas', ['ngFileUpload']);
```

When I run this on NetBeans and do localhost:8088 in Chrome, the console shows the following error:

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider
>
> > Unknown provider: ngFileUploadProvider <- ngFileUpload <- escuelasDeportivasVerLogroCtrl

This happens only when I inject and call back in my controller named ver.logro.controller.js

```
escuelasDeportivas.controller('escuelasDeportivasVerLogroCtrl', ['ngFileUpload'])
```

Well, we know the rest of code is not necessary because it's a fact how to call back libraries...

That's a way says to me my teacher of programming...

But the correct way of angular Cloudinary to do an inject in my controller called ver.logro.controller.js is:

```
var escuelasDeportivas = angular.module('escuelasDeportivas.logro', ['ngFileUpload']);
```

This throws the error:

> root.home.logro

But what and where is this? Well, that is from menu.controller.js. These are the routers of the menu's in the project. But why does this happen? Because it's just an inject?

And in my index.html I already put the script correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
```

If the script is not correct it would throw error 404 not found of the component...

Well this is my first question on StackOverflow and it's difficult for me to talk English because I speak Spanish and I hate translating with Google translate...

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs my friend:

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

In the controller  the injection is 'Upload' and not 'ngFileUpload'

Comment: Well, yes! in the controller is "upload" but that's a way said me my teacher to not injecting and doing a callback injecting from app.js to controller.js, anyway i try the correct way from the docs of cloudinary injecting in the module ngFileUpload and that's do me the error "root.home.logro".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read in the documentation, the service is called Upload, not ngFileUpload

You should use:

```
escuelasDeportivas.controller('escuelasDeportivasVerLogroCtrl', ['Upload'])
```

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#usage

Comment: Well, i need the controller injection not the service, and i try doing the correct argument from docs in Cloudinary doing the same "var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);" but that doing me the error root.home.logro...